# What is the best way to create PDF in PHP to look the same as DOM element?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, mpdf

I want to create a PDF file out of a part of my DOM with a field (div width and height given) and place inside fields with text (position them relatively to this div).

[image]

Also I need to be able to rotate those text layers and apply skew on them.

Tried to use TCPDF and mPDF but unfortunately I couldn't achieve it.
Any ideas how to do it and which library would be the best?

Comment: Use headless Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

With mPDF/TCPDF, you cannot use simple div and style to build page like as HTML. The way is to use table

If you want to use major of CSS 2 features, i thinks you can use the DOMPDF librairy